# How would you collect the All-Night Mask so that you can get the Fierce Deity Mask?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d, zelda-majoras-mask

To collect the Fierce Deity Mask, you need to collect all 20 of the normal non-transformation masks. To get the All-Night Mask, you have to protect the Old Lady from Sakon on the first night but if you do this, Sakon won't come to the Curiosity Shop to sell the Bomb Bag and Kafei won't be able to find his hideout which stops you from completing the Anju & Kafei Quest. If you can't complete the quest from that point, wouldn't you be unable to get the Keaton and Couples Mask?

Comment: I can't believe this is a serious question. You already know this much about how to get which mask, yet you don't know what happens to your masks after you reset the 3 days? Sounds fishy, if you ask me.

Answer (score 6):

When you reset time back to day 1, you keep any collected masks and dungeon items (such as the bow, but not arrows).

All events also reset.